# Azure Functions: how to call an HttpTrigger Function from EventGridTrigger Function

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-http-trigger

I have an `EventGridTrigger` Function which is invoked whenever an event is **published** to the event grid topic.

The default code for this function used to **log** the `eventData` without any issues.

I want to send this data to another HttpTrigger Function (say `OutFunction2`) and log it there.
I can trigger the OutFunction2 from Postman, it works fine.
However, when I try the same request using `xhr2` from my `eventGridTrigger` function,

I get an error saying `Error: The method or operation is not implemented.`

I tried to add package.json and did `npm install` using `Kudu Services`

I still get the above error when I trigger the event from **Test/Run Feature of Azure**.

*function.json* file

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "eventGridEvent",
      "direction": "in"
    }  ]
}
```

*index.js* file

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://my-function-url"; //2nd function url (OutFucntion2)
module.exports = async function (context, eventGridEvent) {
xhr.open("POST", url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json,");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
   }};
var data = JSON.stringify(eventGridEvent.data);
xhr.send(data);
};
```

*package.json* file

```
{
  "name": "eventgrid",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "date": "^2.0.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.1",
    "npm": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

I may be missing something fundamental in **function.json** file, or in **package.json**.

I am not sure what is the correct format to provide an `httpTrigger` outbinding,

Kindly help me with a **function.json** code / rectification.

I am new to *Azure functions and javascript*, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- An alternative would be that Instead of `xhr2` use `axios` where you can easily send the post request with the Json event grid data.
- Just install `axios` using `npm install axios` and then add the following code before the `export.module` function.

```
var axios = require('axios');
```

- Then use post function to call the http trigger and add Json string of the event grid trigger.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(eventGridEvent.data);

axios.post("<url of the http trigger function >",data).then(Response=>context.log(Response.body));
```